# Unable to delete or rename file

Tags: windows-10, pdf, 7-zip

For those who went through most possible solutions online, I hope this save you from headaches.

So a while ago, I had a PDF file that I saved from Google Chrome that had an excessively long name.

Little did I know that Windows will mess things up when a certain file name is too long.

When I decided to delete the PDF when I'm done with it.

It does not budge.

**Literally No error code/message, No indication, Nothing happened to the file**

Also when I attempt to change the filename, nothing happened as well.

**BUT** if  I saved the name as it is, it came up with an error message saying it's too long.

Tried various methods as well:

- uninstall Adobe programs
- using CMD to delete
- booting into safe mode
- using CMD to delete in safe mode
- changing file extension (result is same as deleting and renaming)
- archive the file (failed)

Comment: This site is a professional site, visited by people at work. Use professional language, please.

Comment: Further, while we're glad you fixed this for yourself and happy you came to share your fix, others have already asked this question (and found this precise answer) on this site. :https://superuser.com/search?q=cannot+delete+file+with+long+name

Comment: @music2myear thanks for the feedback, I may have missed that solution after hours of attempts in removing that file.

Comment: @music2myear i have submitted the agreement to the slimilarity, is there anything else I can help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***SOLUTION***

Steps:

1. Download 7zip
2. Open 7zip with admin privilege.
3. Open the directory containing the problematic file.
4. Create a folder and move the problematic file into it.
5. Delete the folder inside the 7 zip interface.